# T sql CONCAT by comma dynamic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have dynamic sql query as below.

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[0],[3],[11]',
        @query    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM 
                (
                   SELECT 
                   year(createdDate) as [year],month(createdDate) as [month],cp.product_Id as product_ID,cp.salesprice as Amount 
                   FROM customer_products cp               
               )s 
               PIVOT 
               (
               SUM(Amount) 
               FOR product_Id IN ( '+ @cols +' )) 
AS pvt;' 

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Question:

Above query works however below query is **not working**  because of

```
 SELECT @cols = CONCAT(@cols, '[', cast(product_ID as varchar),']') FROM Product
```

code block.Error displays **Incorrect syntax near**

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '',
        @query    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = CONCAT(@cols, '[', cast(product_ID as varchar),'],') FROM Product

    SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM 
                    (
                       SELECT 
                       year(createdDate) as [year],month(createdDate) as [month],cp.product_Id as product_ID,cp.salesprice as Amount 
                       FROM customer_products cp               
                   )s 
                   PIVOT 
                   (
                   SUM(Amount) 
                   FOR product_Id IN ( '+ @cols +' )) 
    AS pvt;' 

    EXECUTE(@query)
```

Where i miss exactly what is missing in above query while selecting productID from Product ?

Comment: I guess you need to remove last `,` from @cols

Comment: above query as [0],[3],[11] that is why i added , how can i solve if you say i must remove thanks

Comment: Use `SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)` after concatenating and before defining @query. And see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294417/tsql-pivoting-issue-looking-for-better-approach/32295875#32295875) for sample demo

Comment: @lad2025 thanks it works

Comment: Just as a side note. Before you call `EXEC (@QUERY)` I almost always call a `PRINT @QUERY` so I can see what the dynamic SQL is generating. It saves alot of headaches and keeps you in control of the generated code. A good simple way to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove last `,` from @cols, add

`SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)`

You can consider using XML instead CONCAT like:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CAST(product_ID as VARCHAR(10)))
                      FROM Products
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                    , 1, 1, '');
```

It is a good practice to define length for `cast(product_ID as varchar(10))`

Comment: FYI, if you undefined the length of `varchar` in `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions, default length will be 30 characters. If you undefined the length of `varchar` in variable declaration, default length will be only 1 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the last comma is removed from the select list, or you're passing an empty value to `PIVOT`.

Use this:

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  = '',
        @query    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols+', ','') + '[' + cast(product_ID as varchar) + ']' FROM product

    SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM 
                    (
                       SELECT 
                       year(createdDate) as [year],month(createdDate) as [month],cp.product_Id as product_ID,cp.salesprice as Amount 
                       FROM customer_products cp               
                   )s 
                   PIVOT 
                   (
                   SUM(Amount) 
                   FOR product_Id IN ( '+ @cols +' )) 
    AS pvt;' 

    EXECUTE(@query)
```