# Merging rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following situation (heavily abstracted, please ignore bad design):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PersonTest (Id INT, name VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO dbo.PersonTest
        (Id, name )
VALUES  (1, 'Pete')
,       (1, 'Marie')
,       (2, 'Sam')
,       (2, 'Daisy')
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
Id  Name1   Name2
1   Marie   Pete
2   Daisy   Sam
```

So, for each Id, the rows should be merged.

Getting this result I used the following query:

```
WITH PersonRN AS
(
    SELECT  *
    ,       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY name) RN
    FROM    dbo.PersonTest
)

SELECT      PT1.Id
,           PT1.name Name1
,           PT2.name Name2
FROM        PersonRN AS PT1
LEFT JOIN   PersonRN AS PT2 -- Left join in case there's only 1 name
        ON  PT2.Id = PT1.Id
        AND PT2.RN = 2
WHERE       PT1.RN = 1
```

Which works perfectly fine.

My question is: Is this the best way (best in terms of performance and resilience)? If, for example, one of these Id's has a third name, this third name is ignored by my query. I'm thinking the best way to deal with that would be dynamic SQL, which would be fine, but if it can be done without dynamic, I would prefer that.

Comment: Better way is `PIVOT`, you want to change rows to columns, If you know in advance max number of names self join is good enough.

Comment: You can read [my answer for inspiration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294417/tsql-pivoting-issue-looking-for-better-approach/32295875#32295875) and live demos

Comment: @lad2025 thanks for your link. I had been thinking about `PIVOT` as well, but couldn't get it to work. I haven't used it before, and it isn't as intuitive as I'd like. Guess I'll have to practice some..

Comment: @HoneyBadger i am also trying with `PIVOT` but still not success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from dynamic `PIVOT`, you can do this using [**Dynamic Crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/), which I prefer for readability.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07a75/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(1000) = '',
        @sql2 VARCHAR(1000) = '',
        @sql3 VARCHAR(1000) = ''
DECLARE @max INT

SELECT TOP 1 @max = COUNT(*) FROM PersonTest GROUP BY ID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    ID' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN RN =' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), RN) 
    + ' THEN name END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Name' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), RN)) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT TOP(@max)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
    FROM sys.columns
)t
ORDER BY RN

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY name)
    FROM PersonTest
)t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```