# SQL Pivot STRING column to STRING row

Tags: sql, string, pivot

I always get hung up on using SQL Pivot Table.
All I need to do is change column data:

```
Name       Thing
---------- -----------------
JOE        Glove
JOE        Pants
JOE        Hat
SUE        Hat
SUE        Shirt
MIKE       Shoes
```

To either a grouped, delimited column:

```
Name      Things
--------- -------------------------------------
JOE       Glove | Pants | Hat
SUE       Hat | Shirt
MIKE      Shoes
```

OR, even better, a "ragged right" column for each found item:

```
Name      Thing0 Thing1 Thing2 Thing3
--------- ------ ------ ------ ------
JOE       Glove  Pants  Hat
SUE       Hat    Shirt
MIKE      Shoes
```

Thanks for any help.

-Allen

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at my question and answer therein: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376737/merging-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

For a delimited/aggregated column:

```
SELECT Name, listagg(Things, ' | ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Things)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Name;
```

Your second "ragged right" example is probably best solved using PL/SQL using a dynamic sql statement using the `PIVOT` function if you want individual columns for each Thing.